# Existem paradoxos na computação?

Tags: teoria-da-computação

Há alguns paradoxos na Eletrônica e em outras áreas do conhecimento e esta questão apareceu neste ramo.

Comment: Achei legal a pergunta, mas não vejo uma forma de não encaixá-la como "muito ampla".

Comment: Tive este receio, mas é uma boa questão.

Answer (score -1):

Conforme o jbueno comentou, talvez a pergunta seja muito ampla. Mas eu gosto desse tema e costumo ler bastante sobre paradoxos (não só relacionados a computação, mas a tudo).

Então, não sei se era desse tipo que você queria, mas conheço o [Paradoxo de Moravec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moravec%27s_paradox).

Geralmente, as pessoas tem dificuldades para resolver problemas matemáticos e lógicos de altos níveis de complicação, como equações gigantescas e estratégias perfeitas de xadrez. Por outro lado, seres humanos conseguem fazer outras tarefas como caminhar, cheirar coisas e falar com quase ou nenhum esforço, e para computadores, isto é extremamente difícil, ou até mesmo impossível.

Além do link que deixei para o Wikipedia, você pode ler mais sobre o Paradoxo de Moravec [aqui](https://paradigmaseparadoxos.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/o-paradoxo-de-moravec/)

Comment: Interessante, eu esperava algum lógico matemático, mas tinha esquecido da  área de desempenho e custo computacional.